# How can I get CMake to make a custom script?

Tags: cmake

I have a project that has the following folder structure:

```
src/
|
|- foo/config.ini
|- bar/config.ini
|- tool/
|   | - myscript.sh
|   | - CMakeLists.txt
|- cpp/
    |- main.cpp
    |- baz.cpp
    |- CMakeLists.txt
```

Basically, I want to

- Have a custom target `make foo-target`
- I want `foo-target` to depend on my executable built in `cpp/main.cpp`
- I want `foo-target` to somehow configure `myscript.sh`

  - `myscript.sh` is configured so that it knows where to find `foo/config.ini` (*something like having the absolute path to the ini*)
  - `myscript.sh` is also configured so that it knows where to find the executable built in `cpp/main.cpp`

I have looked into:

- [add_custom_command](https://cmake.org/cmake/help/v3.4/command/add_custom_command.html)
- [add_custom_target](https://cmake.org/cmake/help/v3.4/command/add_custom_target.html)
- [configure_file](https://cmake.org/cmake/help/v3.4/command/configure_file.html)
- Exporting variables to the environment (*via add custom command*)

**But I just can't figure out how to! And could use some help!**

Maybe there are other CMake commands that could help or maybe I am trying something silly that I shouldn't do, any help is appreciated!

*For CMake version 3.4 and above*

Edit:

Here is an example for `myscript.sh`

```
#!/bin/sh
CONFIG_INI=@CONFIG_INI_ABS_PATH@
EXE_PATH=@EXE_ABS_PATH@
 
echo "Config path is $CONFIG_INI"
echo "Exe path is $EXE_PATH"
```

As for the CMakeLists.txt under `tools`

```
set (CONFIG_INI_ABS_PATH ${PROJECT_SOURCE_DIR}/foo/config.ini)
set (EXE_ABS_PATH ${PROJECT_SOURCE_DIR}/cpp/myExe)

# This works, but how can I make it depend on myExe
# And how can I configure it "on command" (i.e. make foo-target)
configure_file(myscript.sh myscript.sh
  USE_SOURCE_PERMISSIONS 
  @ONLY
)

# Can't figure out how to use this one
add_custom_command(OUTPUT myscript.sh
  # COMMAND use sed to modify the bash script? by cahcing all @*@ to what I want?
)

add_custom_target(foo-target
  DEPENDS myExe # I know that I need this to make my target depend on "myExe"
)
```

Comment: `myscript.sh is configured ` what does it mean to "configure a script"? `I just can't figure out how to` Could you be more specific? You do  not know how to add a custom target, or how to depend on executable, or how to configure the script, or how to get path to `foo/config.ini` or how to find the executable built by compilng `cpp/main.cpp`?

Comment: add_custom_command should accomplish what you want, what was the problem with that approach?

Comment: Update the question a little more...
It basically boils down to me not knowing how to properly use the `add_custom_command`, not even sure what to google

Comment: `use sed to modify the bash script?` But why modify? Why not like pass the paths as arguments? What does the script do? Does your script _generates_ some output, or you just want to run it to get two lines of text printed? I.e. is your script stateless or modifies files?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Pass options as arguments to scripts:

```
#!/bin/sh
config_ini=$1
exe_path=$2
 
echo "Config path is $config_ini"
echo "Exe path is $exe_path"
```

Use [generator expression](https://cmake.org/cmake/help/latest/manual/cmake-generator-expressions.7.html) to get path to file of executable. Assuming your script does not generate anything, you could:

```
add_executable(my_exe ...)

find_program(SHELL sh REQUIRED)
add_custom_target(foo-target
     COMMENT "Print two lines"
     COMMAND
          ${SHELL}
          ${CMAKE_CURRENT_SOURCE_DIR}/script.sh
          ${CMAKE_CURRENT_SOURCE_DIR}/foo/config.ini
          $<TARGET_FILE:my_exe>
     DEPENDS 
          ${CMAKE_CURRENT_SOURCE_DIR}/script.sh
          ${CMAKE_CURRENT_SOURCE_DIR}/foo/config.ini 
          $<TARGET_FILE:my_exe>
     VERBATIM
)
```

Do not use `make target_name`. Prefer to use `cmake --build build_dir --target target_name`, so that when you switch to a lot times faster Ninja you will not have to change your scripts.

Comment: sorry for taking so long to answer, personal matters... In the end I ended using something similar to what you stated above, thanks!